# Conditional RedirectMatch

Tags: .htaccess

I have a 302 redirect set up to point to a folder, but this should only affect non-mobile users.

`RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /my-folder-name/`

In order to restrict this to desktop users, I'm trying to filtering out by user agent, like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(iphone|ipod|android|symbian|windows\ phone|blackberry|iemobile|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile)   [NC]
RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /my-folder-name/
```

But this doesn't work. Should I use `RewriteRule` instead of `RedirectMatch`? I tried but couldn't figure out the correct syntax for that – any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Got it. `RedirectMatch` isn't affected by `RewriteCond`.
I ended up using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(iphone|ipod|android|symbian|windows\ phone|blackberry|iemobile|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile)   [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /my-folder-name/ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Yep, `RedirectMatch` and `RewriteCond` are in completely different apache modules: the former is part of [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html), the latter part of the much more powerful [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can put that in the vhost:

```
  <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'thedomain.com' || %{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.thedomain.com'">
  Redirect "/" "https://thedomain.com/"
  </If>
```

Further reference:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if